# Difficulty creating Outlook 2010 Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm trying to create an Outlook 2010 Add-in with Visual Studio, and I'm having all kinds of trouble. The online documentation is highly fragmentory, and is often specific to Word or Excel only. Are there any good tutorials available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at VSTO contrib

- http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-contrib/introduction
- http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-ribbon-designer-in-depth
- http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop

And here is the standard MS doco

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479345.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133459
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/hh128768.aspx

As for your other questions you should split them into different questions to make it easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

Very good tutorials here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128768.aspx